# Is there an simple way to grant specific players permissions by right clicking a item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm working on a server where instead of buying ranks to get access to certain features such as nicknaming and and other donater features commonly found on most Minecraft servers, I'm hoping to add a system where you find one-use items that give you permissions like the ones you find on other servers.

So for example, lets say you are given an item that when right clicked, dissapears from your inventory, and gives you a permission that allows you to change your nickname with a command.

Are there any Plugins or other methods to doing this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craftbook, a plugin made by sk89q (the same guy who made WorldEdit) has the ability to add command items, and it's probably far more customizable than you need :P

[Here is a guide for creating command items using CraftBook](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/CraftBook/Command_Items).

In the commands section you would add a command to run as console to grant the player the new permission. This changes depending on the permissions plugin you're running.

I use LuckPerms, which is awesome, free and probably the best plugin I've ever used, let alone the best permissions plugin ever. For me, the command would look like this:

```
/lp user @p perm set new.permission.node true
```

In this case, the "@p" is replaced with the name of the player that clicked the item, so this would set the permission of whoever clicked the item.

There's some tweaking to do to make sure the item gets consumed and setting some custom lore so players can't just craft the item, but I'll leave that to you.